pandas.DataFrame.query() - how do I access class variables with @?
One uses the '@' character in the query string to refer to variables when using pandas.DataFrame.query(). However, doing so seems to throw an error when you refer to class variables. See example below:
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')

class i:
    j = 5

m = i()

tips.query("size == @i.j") <<< Class Variable in query. Throws error.
tips.query("size == @m.j") <<<< Class Variable via a object in query. Works correctly.


In [1]: import seaborn as sns
In [2]: tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
In [7]: class i:
   ...:     j = 5
   ...: 
In [8]: i.j
Out[8]: 5
In [9]: tips.query("size == @i.j")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/computation/scope.py:231 in resolve
    return self.resolvers[key]
  File /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py:986 in __getitem__
    return self.__missing__(key)            # support subclasses that define __missing__
  File /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py:978 in __missing__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'i'

#Accesing it via an instance works correctly as expected


In [19]: m = i()

In [20]: m.j
Out[20]: 5

In [21]: tips.query("size == @m.j")
Out[21]: 
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
142       41.19  5.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     5
155       29.85  5.14  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     5
185       20.69  5.00    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     5
187       30.46  2.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     5
216       28.15  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     5


Note 1: Class variable used to work. It seems to not now, post upgrade to pandas version 2.2.0. The above output is from pandas version 2.2.0
Note 2: I do know that I can use an f-string in the query to circumvent this problem. I'd like to avoid that if I can. It also doesn't make sense for me to instantiate an object of the class just so that I can use it in the query string.
Has something changed? If so please do point me to any documentation around it.
Thanks!
I've tried googling for information around the same and can't find any.
Update:
Proof that this used to work earlier. The output below is from version 1.4.0
In [5]: import seaborn as sns
   ...: 
   ...: tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: class i:
   ...:     j = 5
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: m = i()
   ...: 

In [6]: tips.query("size == @i.j")
Out[6]: 
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
142       41.19  5.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     5
155       29.85  5.14  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     5
185       20.69  5.00    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     5
187       30.46  2.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     5
216       28.15  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     5

In [7]: tips.query("size == @m.j")
Out[7]: 
     total_bill   tip     sex smoker   day    time  size
142       41.19  5.00    Male     No  Thur   Lunch     5
155       29.85  5.14  Female     No   Sun  Dinner     5
185       20.69  5.00    Male     No   Sun  Dinner     5
187       30.46  2.00    Male    Yes   Sun  Dinner     5
216       28.15  3.00    Male    Yes   Sat  Dinner     5

In [8]: pd.__version__
Out[8]: '1.4.0'


Not at all an answer to your question but are you aware that query has the worst performance vs other methods? Personally I just stay away from it and this would then become a non-issue anyway

I think the first thing to do is to check if it really doesn't work with pandas 2.2.0. It doesn't work with the current collab base (2.0.3). I think we need to confirm with various pandas versions that it really does not work from 2.2.0 before we can discuss it.

@roganjosh : Thank you. I didn't know that. My scripts are pretty basic, so the performance isn't much of a problem. But it is good to bear this in mind for the future!

@PandaKim : I've edited the post to clarify that the output was from 2.2.0. I've also added new output from 1.4.0 to show that it used to work.

The pandas.DataFrame.query() uses an underlying eval() function to try to resolve a variable referenced within a string, such as @i.j. At the time when you run the line tips.query("size == @i.j"), the variable i is a class and not in the local scope, or can't be referenced properly.
Now, you said it used to work before, so if I'm taking that at face value: the change could be related to how python handles local runtime env in regards to classes (you'll see that the error actually comes from python3.10/collections). Did you change up your python env/version perhaps?
The easiest approach without modifying much is to actually assign a variable like x = i.j to see if pandas query using @ will be able to grab that value. You don't have to instantiate an entirely new class instance. And without knowing the full use-case example, which I understand could be way more complex than the minimal reproducible example... why can't you have a variable that contains the necessary values you need, outside of the class? (rethinking how the class is actually used).
Like @roganjosh mentioned, query doesn't have good performance, on top of the eval that gets tricky with variables references within strings, it might be worth looking into alternative ways to "query" using pandas syntax, e.g.
tips[tips['size'] == m.j]
tips[tips['size'] == i.j]


Thank you. I've added outputs to the post to clarify that it was working earlier.

As to the other points raised:

Classes are first class objects in python - so I don't see why this should be a problem.
Yes, I ended up creating variables for these and used them in the query strings. But creating variables just for this purpose doesn't sound right. At best - a hack, to get query to work.
In my actual use-case, these values are enums (i.e., the class is derived from Enum). That is why they are class variables.
query is convenient - For my simple script, performance doesn't really matter. But its good to know this and bear in mind. Thanks.

